# Selectize.js - Differences between the onInitialize event and the load method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, combobox, selectize.js

I would like to ask you if an **"onInitialize"** event of **selectize.js** with ajax call can replace the **"load"** method to load new options from the server.